# Trouble with procedure in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, stored-procedures

Im trying to create a procedure for my database via migrations in Laravel 5.3. The database user 'apptutor_usr' has the privileges of a super user.
The code for my procedure is as below:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`  
  apptutor_usr@68.65.120.22` PROCEDURE `signup_update` ( IN  `s_name` VARCHAR  
  ( 50 ) , IN  `s_displaypicture` VARCHAR( 100 ) )  BEGIN SET @uid = ( SELECT student_p  
  arent_id                                                                     
  FROM student_parent                                                          
  WHERE email = s_email ) ;                                                                                                                         
  END
```

But this gives me an error as below

> String 'apptutor_usr@68.65.120.22' is
>     too long for user name (should be no longer than 16)

The thing is I cant have a user less than 16 characters as my hosting's cpanel already has 'apptutor_' pre set beforehand.

Comment: Did you try to create it using some database manager? Maybe new line before `apptuto...` is a problem?

Comment: There is no new line, indentation error while posting on stackoverflow

Comment: The definer should be `'user'@'host'`, so `'apptutor_usr'@'68.65.120.22'`. Quotes instead of ticks, and you need to separate each side. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: @aynber I have actually tried that aswell, it gives this error:
`Syntax error or access violation: 1227 Access denied; you   
  need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation`

Comment: That error meant the syntax is fine, but the user is not. So either give your user SUPER privs, or use a user that does.

Comment: I actually have granted all the privs to this user, and when im trying to run thsi command on terminal: 
`mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR ‘apptutor_usr'@'68.65.120.22';`
it just takes me in a endless wait.

Answer (score 1):

You incorrectly define the user name, use `'username'@'host'` format:

```
CREATE DEFINER='apptutor_usr'@'68.65.120.22' ...
```

Actually, your user name is only `'apptutor_usr'`, not the entire `'apptutor_usr'@'68.65.120.22'`.

Comment: I have tried this aswell, the error I get with this is : `Syntax error or access violation: 1227 Access denied; you   
  need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation`

Comment: This is an entirely different question, which should be posted separately. Btw the error message is clear: your user (not the one in the definer) needs super privilege.

Comment: let me post the comment from the above thread here aswell:

'I actually have granted all the privs to this user, and when im trying to run thsi command on terminal: mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR ‘apptutor_usr'@'68.65.120.22'; it just takes me in a endless wait.'

Comment: Pls read my above comment again, I have nothing to add. This question is answered.